# What is the difference between function and function*

Tags: javascript, function, generator, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

What is the difference between generator functions created with `function` and `function*`

```
function a(i){
    for(;i>0;i--){
        yield i*i;
    }
}
function *b(i){
    for(;i>0;i--){
        yield i*i*i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen like this question, but currently couldn't find...

Comment: Or this one: [What purpose of asterisk (*) in ES6 generator functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778105/what-purpose-of-asterisk-in-es6-generator-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generators created with `function` are part of earlier ES6 draft.

```
//They have differrent prototypes
console.log(a.prototype.constructor.constructor,b.prototype.constructor.constructor);//function Function() function GeneratorFunction()
let a1=a(10);
let b1=b(10);
//both create generators...
console.log(a1,b1);//Generator {  } Generator {  }
//but different generators: one returns value, another returns an object of special format
console.log(a1.next(),b1.next());//100 Object { value: 1000, done: false }
for(let a2 of a1)console.log(a2);
for(let b2 of b1)console.log(b2);
//They are equal when used in for ... of.
```